# wxpython aui manager pane's with tabs by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

So I want to two aui pane to be "stacked" or "tabed" like this.
[image]

However I can't find any documentation that explains how to do this without starting the application and using the mouse to stack the pane's

Also I don't want to use aui.notebook

tried chatgpt to get answer however it doesn't work
[image]

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the AuiManager object
        self._mgr = aui.AuiManager(self)

        # create the panes
        pane1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Pane 1")
        pane2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Pane 2")

        # add the panes to the AuiManager and stack them vertically
        self._mgr.AddPane(pane1, aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("pane1").Caption("Pane 1").Left())
        self._mgr.AddPane(pane2, aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("pane2").Caption("Pane 2").Bottom().Layer(1).Position(1))

        # configure the AuiManager
        self._mgr.Update()

# create the app and frame
app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the AuiManager object
        self._mgr = aui.AuiManager(self)

        # create the panes
        pane1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Pane 1")
        pane2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Pane 2")

        # add the panes to the AuiManager and stack them vertically
        self._mgr.AddPane(pane1, aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("P1").Caption("P1-Caption").Center().MinSize((10, 10)).BestSize((200, 100)))
        self._mgr.AddPane(pane2, aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("P2").Caption("P2-Caption").Center().MinSize((10, 10)).BestSize((200, 100)),\
                         target=self._mgr.GetPane("P1")) # target stacks the pane's to tabs

        # configure the AuiManager
        self._mgr.Update()

# create the app and frame
app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```